# Ни один из контекстов Toast.makeText не подходит

Tags: java, android

Код ниже. Задача - вывести путь к файлу + само имя файла во всплывающем тексте. Так-то я это сам всё указал, но надо именно получить и вывести (делаю под Android в Android Studio). С обычным текстом всё работает, но при попытке добавить собственно считывание текста и имя файла я получаю ошибку **this' cannot be referenced from a static context** при использовании контекста *this*, а при любом другом контексте вроде *Application()*, *Service()* и т. д. на выходе ошибка **Cannot resolve method '*контекст*' in 'FileTest'**. Какой контекст надо подставить, чтоб работало?

Код:

````
{
    public static void onClickFiles()
    {
        File fl = new File("storage/emulated/0/Download/app-debug.apk");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, fl.getAbsolutePath() + fl .getName());
        toast.show();
    }
}```
````

Comment: У вас метод `onClickFiles` отмечен как статичный, поэтому внутри него нельзя использовать `this`, т.к. `this` это ссылка на текущий объект класса. Не вижу причин делать метод статичным

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Эта ошибка исчезла. 
Но вылезла другая проблема, теперь просто "_Cannot resolve method 'makeText(com.example.myapplication.FileTest, java.lang.String)'_".

Comment: Погуглил `Toast.makeText` в примере нашел, что нужно указывать не `this`, а `getApplicationContext()`: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/toast.php

Comment: @gil9red пытался, но тоже Cannot resolve method(

Comment: А, ну понятно... В makeText 3 параметра, поэтому и ругается. Вам нужно уметь читать ошибки, смотреть варианты функций и смотреть документацию :) Добавил ответ

Answer (score 1):

В классе [Toast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast) есть такие варианты функции `makeText`:

- [public static Toast makeText (Context context, int resId, int duration)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int))
- [public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int))

Обе имеют 3 параметра.

Вам нужно так поменять свой код:

```
File fl = new File("storage/emulated/0/Download/app-debug.apk");
String text = fl.getAbsolutePath() + fl.getName();
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Третий параметр имеет такие варианты значений:

- [Toast.LENGTH_SHORT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#LENGTH_SHORT)
- [Toast.LENGTH_LONG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#LENGTH_LONG)

Comment: И снова _Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext' in 'FileTest'_

Comment: @Yaroslav, ок, значит ваш `FileTest` не является классом, имеющий контекст приложения. Вам нужно прокинуть объект контекста пример: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819059/5909792